# Transform attribute text to capatilize in WooCommerce variation select

Tags: css, woocommerce, attributes, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I have hidden the label of the variation box with CSS and added a custom text to the select box containing the name of the attribute. This is the code I used for that:

```
function filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args( $array ) { 

    $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($array['attribute']);
    $select_text = 'Choose an ' . $attribute_name;

    $array['show_option_none'] = __( $select_text, 'woocommerce' );
    return $array; 
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 10, 1 );
```

CSS for hiding the label:

```
.variations th.label {
  display: none;
}
```

Now I just want to make this sentence capatilized but I can't find the right css for this. I'm almost sure I need to use `text-transform: capatilize` but I'm not sure where to add it and most important with which css class/id. Can I add it to the snippet maybe?

I tried some answers from similar questions here but they all didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `$select_text = strtoupper( 'Choose an ' . $attribute_name );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args( $array ) { 

    $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($array['attribute']);
    $select_text = ucwords( 'Choose an ' . $attribute_name );
    

    $array['show_option_none'] = __( $select_text, 'woocommerce' );
    return $array; 
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 10, 1 );
```

Please check the links for changing the string case to [upper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php), [lower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php), [capitalize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)...

Comment: This was doing the trick changing `$select_text = ucwords( 'Choose an ' . $attribute_name );` to `$select_text = ucfirst(strtolower('Choose an ' . $attribute_name));`. So I was going from 'Choose an *Atrribute name*' to 'Choose an *attribute name*'. Thanks!